# Most efficient jquery show/hide Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple question:

What is the most efficient way of showing/hiding 2 divs based on a select control using jquery?

```
<div id="div1">DIV 1 BRO</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">THIS BE DIV 2 CUZ</div>

<select id="blablabla">
    <option value="div1">div1</option>
    <option value="div2">div2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go: **Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/qPUGL/

API: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

**Code**

```
$('#blablabla').change(function(){
    $("#div1,#div2").toggle()
});​
```

Comment: Perfect. Don't know why I didn't think of that.  I was trying to avoid if statements etc.  This is perfect. Thx!

Comment: @KingKongFrog All saweet as `cuz` :P Glad it helped!

Comment: #1 cause of the bro comments. haha

Answer (score 0):

Check this JsFiddle [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rTe3q/)

Using slideToggle function it looks nice